# Problems about python io.BytesIO handling large content

Tags: python-3.x, io, pysftp

I am currently using pysftp with io to parse some docs on a server. A problem appeared when there is an extremly large doc. Here is my code:

```
with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=user_name, password=pass_word, private_key=".ppk", cnopts=cnopts) as mysftp:
    with io.BytesIO() as fl:
        mysftp.getfo(TargetDoc,fl) 
        content=fl.getvalue()
```

When the TargetDoc has an extremly large size, it takes ages to do the step and sometime it will be kicked out by the server. Since I only want to parse the first serveral lines of the TargetDoc. Is there any ideal on how to partially parse the doc? Any suggestions or advises will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of thinking, I found a way to approach this task...

```
with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=usn, password=psw, private_key=".ppk", cnopts=cnopts) as mysftp:
    with mysftp.open(TargetPath,mode='r',bufsize=-1) as f:
        line=f.readline()
```

Hope it can help someone else in the future.